# Problem downloading iPhone/iOS upgrade, iTunes complains: "You do not have enough access privileges for this operation"

Tags: iphone, itunes, upgrade

When trying to upgrade my iPhone running iOS 4.1 to 4.2, iTunes displays the error message saying:

> There was a problem downloading the software for the iPhone "[Username]'s iPhone". You do not have enough access privileges for this operation.

I kept trying the upgrade process repeatedly, but with no luck. Everything else, including app and music downloads, works fine. I'm running iTunes 10 on MacOS 10.6. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix [on the Apple Discussions board](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12630249#12632003):

1. Go to `~/Library/` (i.e. open your home directory, then select the `Library` folder)
2. Get Info (click `File` -> `Get Info` or type ⌘I)
3. If possible, make sure the lock at the bottom right corner of the Get Info window is unlocked
4. Make sure the `Sharing & Permissions:` section is visible
5. Where it says "Username (me)" make sure the privilege is set to `Read & Write`
6. In the little tool/wheel pulldown right below, select `Apply to enclosed items` (say yes, if it asks you if you know it can't be undone)
7. Try the upgrade again

This worked for me. Hope it helps!